# price range vs costs between

Tags: phrase-request, prepositional-phrases, quantifiers

Last week, my friends and I talked about buying computers. We came up with four different ways of saying how much we would spend on a computer. I am going to write them down below.

(1) I want to buy a computer that costs between $700 and $1000.

(2) I want to buy a computer between $700 and $1000.

(3) I want to buy a computer in the price range **from** $700 to $1000.

(4) I want to buy a computer in the price range **of** $700 to $1000.

Which one(s) is/are grammatically correct? Thanks a lot.

Comment: They're all fine (as is *the price range $700 to $1000*, with no preposition).

Answer (score 2):

All your examples are correct and understandable in terms of what you probably mean, that is the listed price of the computer item.

The only difference might be that "the computer is in a price range of" (listed price) may be different than what it "costs" since certain places may not include taxes in the listed price, as in the US. I ran into this with friends from the UK where the posted price is what one pays.